# Can the negation introduction rule of inference "a, b=>¬a / ¬b" be used instead of the usual "b=>a, b=>¬a / ¬b"?

Tags: logic

I find the negation introduction rule which I learned at university a bit confusing to reason out and think that "a, b=>¬a / ¬b" makes more sense as it means that if b implies something which is not true, then b is itself not true. I can't seem to find an example of where the usual rule is more useful than the one I would like to use. Is there a reason why "b=>a, b=>¬a / ¬b" is used as a rule?

Comment: probably a better venue for this is math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Could you kindly edit your question and put normal logical operators there? ¬ is NOT, ok... => is standard, too... What is your "/" in a logical expression? What is ,(comma)? You mean it as AND? Use &,|, ¬, =>, (,). or AND,OR,NOT, XOR. You are looking for a better way of expression? - start with understandable elements.

Comment: Maybe if you look at this notation you'd understand them better?
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formal_Logic/Sentential_Logic/Inference_Rules

Comment: um, neither the / or , is used on the above mentioned page. Did you post the correct link?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK, I think I have a pretty rigorous argument which validates said replacement.

Let's say that we need to introduce a negation on P. So using the usual inference rule, we prove
P => Q
P => ¬Q
and thereby prove ¬P.

Let's say that there is no way to derive both Q and ¬Q if P is not assumed. But then from P we can derive Q /\ ¬Q which will allow us to derive anything, including the negation of a tautology.

So we can prove ¬P using the proposed rule by doing something like this:

```
1.  |P                 Assumed
... |...
10. |Q
... |...
20. |¬Q
21. |Q /\ ¬Q           /\ introduction on line 10 and 20
22. |¬(A => A)         Derived from line 21 using contradiction lemma
23. P => ¬(A => A)     => introduction on lines 1-22
24. A => A             Anything implies itself (a tautology)
25. ¬P                 ¬ introduction on line 23 and 24
```

So using tautologies we can always use the proposed rule of inference.

In other words, if you can use the usual rule of inference to introduce a negation, you can use the proposed rule of inference too.